# Excel Pivot table sports fixture

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a sports fixture and I want to be able to easily count the number of times each team plays each other (and other assorted things).

Columns are Round, Date, Home Team, Away Team, Venue
Rows are each round entry (eg Round 1 Team A v Team B)

I can't seem to work out the correct way to capture this using a pivot table. Ideally what I want to see is that "Melbourne Victory" plays "Sydney FC" twice (for example). Regardless of home/away.

Second problem would be to see if I added last year's finalists, can I also count have many times each team plays the finalists.

Hope this makes sense. Sorry I can't post an image as I don't have "10 reputation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't seem to be captured using a pivot (by me at least). However with formula's it can be. Using the formula =COUNTIFS. See the example below. In a similar fashion it would be possible to see how many times each team plays last year's finalists. Hope this helps.

[image]